# Generate traffic with a specified throughput

Tags: networking

To test my network, I want to send x MB/s between two hosts. I know that `ping` can be used to send a good amount of data, but I need a solution where I can set the bandwidth (it does not have to be really precise).

```
$ sendTrafic --throughput 10M 10.0.0.1
```

Any idea how I can do that? I thought about a script running `scappy` x times per second, but there should be something better.

---

EDIT: I used the following solution:

```
# On receiving node:
iperf -s -u

# On sending node:
iperf -c <ip> -u -b 10m -t 30
```

Which configures the first host as a UDP server, and the second one as a UDP client who send 10Mb/s for 30 seconds.

Thank everyone for your help.

Comment: https://iperf.fr/  why don't you give it a try? hope this helps .

Comment: I would also suggest to use iperf.

Comment: I'll third `iperf`. If you can't install something on both hosts, also have a look at `bwping`.

Comment: @Nakrule depending of your goal, sending UDP packet at a fix rate will only validate the stability of the line with a fixed traffic (you will see in the result how many lost packet). If you want to test your max throughput you need to use TCP. `iperf` is not know to be a very accurate solution, there's a lot of side effect, specially when using it cross-platform. Do a lot of testing if you want to validate a bitrate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't want to install `iperf` (which is not the most reliable tool I've use in the past IMHO), you can use `pv` and `netcat`
You would first need to install `pv` and `netcat` (it's available in most distro).
On the receiving site you will need a listening socket on a reachable port:

```
#if you want the output you can remove the redirection or redirect it to a different file.
#if you want to listen to a TCP port below 1024 you will need to use root
nc -l 4444 > /dev/null
```

On the sending machine you will use this command :

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1000 count=1000 | pv -L 10M | nc <ip> 4444
```

`dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1000 count=1000` will send blocks of 1000 random characters (1000 Bytes) 1000 time: 1000B * 1000 = 1MB . You can adjust the count to increase the amount of data send.
`pv -L 10M`: will limit the write rate to 10 mebibytes/s (*1024).
`netcat <ip> 4444` will send the data to the IP on port TCP 4444.

You adapt to send more data  or even real file using :

```
cat /some/files| pv -L 1M | nc <ip> 4444
```

and on the other side :

```
 nc -l 4444 > /some/destinationfiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there are more integrated projects addressing this more systematically already.

E.g.: in the set of minimalistic ones - [flowgrind](https://github.com/flowgrind/flowgrind) or [trafgen](https://github.com/netsniff-ng/netsniff-ng/tree/master/trafgen)

Simply look out for "rate limited traffic generators".